# Ruby on Rails query by datetime range ( last 24, 48, etc... hours )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, range

I'm trying to build a query that will search for recent entries based on column 'last_login_at'. This is a datetime field with time zone (i.e. `Time.zone.now`)
When I execute

```
User.find(:all, :conditions => ["last_login_at < ?", 24.hours.ago])
```

I get nothing.

Alternatively I can define today as `Time.zone.today` and yesterday as `Time.zone.today - 1.day`
and run

```
User.find(:all, :conditions => ["last_login_at between ? and ?", today, yesterday])
```

and it still returns 0 results. I know there are some entries that fall into this category.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ensure that the timezones you have recorded within the database and those your rails app is outputting are equal. This can sometimes cause an issue. Otherwise try this named scope:

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   named_scope :last_loggedin_before, lambda { |time_ago| { :conditions => ['last_login_at   < ?', time_ago] } }
   named_scope :last_loggedin_within, lambda { |time_ago| { :conditions => ['last_login_at   > ?', time_ago] } }
 end
```

allowing you to do:

```
 User.last_loggedin_before 24.hours.ago
```

or

```
 User.last_loggedin_within 24.hours.ago
```

Comment: It seems that the timezones im comparing are both PST -08:00, so im still stuck there ... 

The named scopes should work great! thanks

Comment: This works great, thanks. One note - named_scope has changed to just 'scope' (I'm on Rails 3.2.11).

Answer (score 20):

Old question, but here's newer syntax:

```
User.where(last_login_at: 3.days.ago..DateTime.now)
```

Comment: That's nice, but keep in mind 3.days.ago doesn't start from the beginning of the day (00), so it'll skip records created before that day but before that time. Check `3.days.ago.beginning_of_day`.